# From the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(H_n-\ln n-\gamma-\frac1{2n}\right)$ to $\zeta(\frac12+it)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

Here is a pretty series

> $$
> \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \left(H_{n}-\ln n-\gamma -\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\ln (2\pi)+\gamma\right) \tag{*}
> $$

where $H_{n}:=\sum_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ are the harmonic numbers and $\gamma := \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (H_n- \ln n)$ is the Euler constant.

$$ $$

> Now just introduce a parameter in the general term of the series and you get a link with... the Riemann $\zeta$ function on the critical line!

Q 1. What proof would you give for (*)?

Q 2. What elements would you give to get the link with $\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)$?

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly you mean by "introduce a parameter in the term of the series". My first guess is that you intended that we create a power series in the parameter using the series terms as coefficients: $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \left(H_{n}-\ln n-\gamma -\frac{1}{2n}\right)z^n$. Is that correct?

Comment: A similar series is given by http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28n%3D1%3Ainf%2CHarmonicNumber%5Bn%5D-log%28n%2B1%2F2%29-1%2F%2824n%5E2%29-gamma%29

Comment: AMM made it a problem 12194.

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you for the information. Actually, only the first part of my question above is considered in the AMM problem.

Comment: See [Sum of Cosine Integral function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222589/on-mathrm-sum-limits-x-1-infty-cix) for an almost same answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Observe that 
$$
H_{n}-\ln n-\gamma -\frac{1}{2n} = \psi (n) - \ln n + \frac{1}{2n}
$$
where $\psi := \Gamma'/\Gamma$ is the digamma function, using $\displaystyle \psi (n)=  H_{n-1}-\gamma = H_n-\gamma- \frac{1}{n}$, $n\geq 1$.

Our initial series thus rewrites 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \psi(n )- \log n + \frac{1}{2n}\right)  = \frac{\gamma}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)+ \frac{1}{2},
$$
(proved by David H).

Then consider the one parameter series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\psi(n \alpha)- \log (n \alpha) + \frac{1}{2n \alpha}\right), \quad \alpha >0.
$$
We have the following result.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be positive real numbers such that $ \alpha\beta=1$.
>
> Then
>   \begin{align}
> &\sqrt{\alpha}\left\{\frac{\gamma-\log(2\pi\alpha)}{2\alpha}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\psi(n \alpha)- \log (n \alpha) + \frac{1}{2n \alpha}\right)\right\}\\
> = & \sqrt{\beta}\left\{\frac{\gamma-\log(2\pi\beta)}{2\beta}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\psi(n \beta)- \log (n \beta) + \frac{1}{2n \beta}\right)\right\} \\
> = &-\frac{1}{\pi^{3/2}}\int_0^{\infty}\left|\xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{it}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{-1+it}{4}\right)\right|^2
> \frac{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\log\alpha\right)}{1+t^2}dt,
> \end{align}

where  $$ \xi(s):=\frac{s(s-1)}{2} \displaystyle \pi^{-s/2}\:\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s)$$ and where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Now express $\displaystyle  \left|\xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{it}{2}\right)\right|^2 $ in terms of $\left|\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+ it\right)\right|^2$ and you obtain the evocated link.

Theorem 1 is due to Ramanujan and one may find [a recent proof](http://dauns.math.tulane.edu/~adixit/zeta_updated.pdf) here.

Here is a related result I have found.

> **Theorem 2.** Let $\Re \alpha >0$.
>
> Then
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \! \left(\! \psi(\alpha n )- \log (\alpha n ) + \frac{1}{2 \alpha n }\! \right)\! =\! \displaystyle \frac{1+\gamma-\log(2\pi)}{2} \\ -\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha (1-x^{1/\alpha})}-\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\alpha}\!\right)\!\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-x}.$$

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like for $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$ the last integral has a form $p+q\ln\alpha+\pi\tau$, where $p,q\in\mathbb Q$, and $\tau$ is an algebraic number. I could not find general expressions for those coefficients.

Answer (score 17):

**Proof of (*)**

Adding the four finite sums,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}H_{k}=(n+1)H_{n}-n,$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln{k}=\ln{n!},$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\gamma=\gamma\,n,$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}=\frac12H_{n},$$

gives us a representation of the $n$-th partial sum for the infinite series. Writing the infinite series as the limit of partial sums, we get:

$$\begin{align}
S
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(H_{k}-\ln{n}-\gamma-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(H_{k}-\ln{n}-\gamma-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((n+1)H_{n}-n-\ln{n!}-\gamma\,n-\frac12H_{n}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(n+\frac12\right)H_{n}-(1+\gamma)n-\ln{n!}\right).
\end{align}$$

Use Stirling's approximation for the factorial to obtain an asymptotic formula for the log-factorial term in the series:

$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\\
\implies \ln{n!}\sim\ln{\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)}=\left(n+\frac12\right)\ln{n}-n+\frac12\ln{(2\pi)}.$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
S
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(n+\frac12\right)H_{n}-(1+\gamma)n-\ln{n!}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(n+\frac12\right)H_{n}-(1+\gamma)n-\left(n+\frac12\right)\ln{n}+n-\frac12\ln{(2\pi)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(n+\frac12\right)H_{n}-\gamma\,n-\left(n+\frac12\right)\ln{n}\right)-\frac12\ln{(2\pi)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\left(H_{n}-\gamma-\ln{n}\right)+\frac12\left(H_{n}-\ln{n}\right)\right)-\frac12\ln{(2\pi)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(H_{n}-\gamma-\ln{n}\right)+\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(H_{n}-\ln{n}\right)-\frac12\ln{(2\pi)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(H_{n}-\gamma-\ln{n}\right)+\frac12\gamma-\frac12\ln{(2\pi)}\\
&=\frac12+\frac12\gamma-\frac12\ln{(2\pi)}.~~~\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

---

**Appendix:**

Using the asymptotic series for the digamma function given by Eq.16 on [this Wolfram Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html),

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(H_{n}-\gamma-\ln{n}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\Psi{(n+1)}-\ln{n}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2\ell}}{2\ell n^{2\ell}}\right)\\
&=\frac12-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2\ell}}{2\ell n^{2\ell-1}}\\
&=\frac12.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for this correct answer to the first part of the question. (+1)

Comment: Do you mean $\log k $ in the second sum?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yes, you are right. The formula has now been corrected. :)

Answer (score 7):

Since
$$
1+\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac1k-\log\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)\right)=H_n-\log(n)
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
H_n-\log(n)-\gamma
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\left(\log\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)-\frac1k\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)-\frac1{k+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\frac1{2n}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac12\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
H_n-\log(n)-\gamma-\frac1{2n}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)-\frac12\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1k\right)\right)
$$
Summing, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n-\log(n)-\gamma-\frac1{2n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)-\frac12\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1k\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^k\left(\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)-\frac12\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1k\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)-\frac12\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1k\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^nk\left(\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)-\frac12\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1k\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(k-1)\log(k)-\sum_{k=1}^nk\log(k)-\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{2(k+1)}\right)\\
&=\color{#C00000}{n\log(n+1)}\color{#00A000}{-\log(n!)-n}\color{#0000F0}{+\frac12(H_{n+1}-1)}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{n\log(n)+1+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)}\color{#00A000}{-\left(n+\frac12\right)\log(n)-\frac12\log(2\pi)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)}\\
&\color{#0000F0}{+\frac12\log(n)+\frac12\gamma-\frac12+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)}\\
&=\frac12\left(1+\gamma-\log(2\pi)\right)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n-\log(n)-\gamma-\frac1{2n}\right)=\frac{1+\gamma-\log(2\pi)}2}
$$

Comment: Nice proof! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Some generalizations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\boxed{\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n
\left ( H_n-\gamma-\ln n-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{12n^2}  \right ) = \frac{5}{24}+\frac{\gamma}{12}-\ln A\\
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^2
\left ( H_n-\gamma-\ln n-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{12n^2}  \right ) = \frac{1}{24}-\frac{\zeta(3)}{4\pi^2}\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n^4\left ( H_n-\gamma
-\ln n-\frac{1}{2n} +\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{120n^4}   \right )
=\frac{59}{240}-\frac{93\zeta(5)}{4\pi^4} \\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}n^4
\left(H_n^{(2)}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{6n^3}    \right)
=\frac{\ln2}{2}-\frac{1}{3}
\end{aligned}}\\ \\
&\boxed{\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\left ( H^{(3)}_n-\zeta(3) \right )
= -\frac{1}{8}\zeta(3)\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}n\left ( H^{(3)}_n-\zeta(3) \right )
= \frac{\pi^2}{24} -\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}n^2\left ( H^{(3)}_n-\zeta(3) +\frac{1}{2n^2} \right )
= \frac{\ln2}{2} -\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\frac{1}{4}\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}n^3\left ( H^{(3)}_n-\zeta(3) +\frac{1}{2n^2} -\frac{1}{2n^3} \right)
=\frac{7}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac{3}{4}\ln2 +\frac{1}{8}\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}n^4\left ( H^{(3)}_n-\zeta(3) +\frac{1}{2n^2} -\frac{1}{2n^3}+\frac{1}{4n^4} \right)
=\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{9}{24}\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}n^5\left ( H^{(3)}_n-\zeta(3) +\frac{1}{2n^2} -\frac{1}{2n^3}+\frac{1}{4n^4} \right)
=-\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)+\frac{5}{4}\ln2-\frac{5}{16}
\end{aligned} }\\ \\
&\boxed{\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left ( H^{(4)}_n -\frac{\pi^4}{90} \right )
= -\frac{\pi^4}{1440}\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n\left ( H^{(4)}_n -\frac{\pi^4}{90} \right )
=\frac{3}{8}\zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^4}{192}\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n^2\left ( H^{(4)}_n -\frac{\pi^4}{90} \right )
=-\frac{9}{24}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{24}\\
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n^3\left ( H^{(4)}_n -\frac{\pi^4}{90}+\frac{1}{3n^3}  \right ) 
= -\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac{\pi^4}{384}+\frac{\ln2}{2} +\frac{1}{6}
\end{aligned}}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Start from the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}
\left ( \psi^{(0)}(1+x)-\ln x\right ) \text{d}x
=-\frac{\pi\zeta(1-s)}{\sin\pi s}$$
Where $0<s<1$.
And
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} 
\frac{-\pi\zeta(1-s)}{\sin(\pi s)}z^{-s}\text{d}s
=\psi^{(0)}(1+z)-\ln z
$$
Where $0<c<1$.
Thus we have
$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta\left ( \frac{1}{2}+it  \right ) }{\cosh(\pi t)}\text{d}t  = 2\gamma-2\\
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta\left ( -\frac{1}{2}-it  \right ) \zeta\left ( \frac{3}{2}+it  \right )}{\cosh(\pi t)}\text{d}t
=\gamma-\ln(2\pi)+1
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but contains information that may be useful in building one.

There are closed form expressions for $H_n-log\left(n\right)$ and $\gamma$ that come from generalized Mercator series.

$$
H_n-log\left(n\right)=1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=nk+1}^{n(k+1)}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)
$$
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602945/134791

$$
\gamma= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{n}-\sum_{j=n(n-1)+1}^{n(n+1)} \frac{1}{j}\right)
$$

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591256/134791

Comment: Thank you for reviewing and commenting, @kamil09875. I added the intended warning "this is not an answer" as soon as I noticed downvotes. However, I believe this adds relevant information and is too long for a comment. Having seen other "non-answers" written in the answer box rather than as a comment for length reasons, it seemed appropriate to me in this case, as well. Would you move this to a comment or simply delete it?

Comment: If a comment is too long, attach it as an answer but make sure that you include a proper message. It will prevent it from reviewing as "not an answer". I've compensated the score of this post.