# Does Euler-Mascheroni constant belong to the ring of periods?

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant, constants

I wonder whether $\gamma$ belongs to the [ring of periods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods)?

UPDATE Well now I know it should not. But $e^{-\gamma}$ should.

Comment: The irrationality of $\gamma$ is a long-standing conjecture. However, it is widely believed that $\gamma\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: This is an open question.

Comment: Does the existence of the following series help to solve the question?
$$
\gamma= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{n}-\sum_{j=n(n-1)+1}^{n(n+1)} \frac{1}{j}\right)
$$
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591256/134791

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, it is expected not to be a period. On the other hand,  it *could* even be rational. So, we do not know for sure that it is *not* a period.

Comment: Expected by whom not to be period?

Comment: The issue is, AFAIK, that $e$ is expected not to be a period either. Even the idea of adding $e$ was  entertained to define "exponential periods" and there you might have it.

Comment: Also it says on Wikipedia "It is not expected that Euler's number e and Euler–Mascheroni constant γ are periods. The periods can be extended to exponential periods by permitting the product of an algebraic function and the exponential function of an algebraic function as an integrand. This extension includes all algebraic powers of e, the gamma function of rational arguments, and values of Bessel functions. If, further, Euler's constant is added as a new period, then according to Kontsevich and Zagier "all classical constants are periods in the appropriate sense"."

Comment: Regarding $e$, it is clear not a period, there is little doubt. Not the case with $\gamma$ though. Even more than $\gamma$, $e^{-\gamma}$ is likely to be a period.

Comment: @Anixx, in what possible sense is it «clear» that e is not a period?!?!?!