# Finding the equality of the natural logarithm to the limit and the infinite series (proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms

I'm trying to proof this equality which I found on this website:

[Euler-Mascheroni constant expression, further simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46713/euler-mascheroni-constant-expression-further-simplification)

$$\ln(n)=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\sum\limits _{a=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{kn-a}-\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\frac{n-1}{kn}.$$

My wolfram Mathematica code:

Limit[sum(k=1)^M sum(a=1)^(n-1) 1/(kn-a) - sum(k=1)^M (n-1)/(kn), M -> infinity]

And it gives me this answer:

(1/kn)infinity (1-n+kn Polygamma[0,1-nk]-kn Polygamma [o,n-nk])

And that is not what I expected, so I tried to write the last sum $$\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\frac{n-1}{kn}$$ as the harmonic series: $$\frac{(n-1)*Hm}{n}$$ were $$Hm=\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\frac{1}{k}$$

So we got:

$$\ln(n)=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\sum\limits _{a=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{kn-a}-\frac{(n-1)*Hm}{n}$$

And now I've no idea to complete the equality that it gives me the answer that I was looking for, so does anyone know how to complete this proof?

Comment: The [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) is related to [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) by the formula $\psi_0(n+1)~=~H_n-\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: @Lucian Yeah I know that! But my question by this equasion is: Can someone tell me me step by step the development of proving that this is equal!?

Comment: Someone already has.

Comment: Were??????????????

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209407). As I said, let $n=3$, and “spell out” the $($general$)$ formula in a more “user-friendly” manner, then prove it using a trick similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1200014/1) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the equality
$$ \frac{1}{s} = \int_0^1 x^{s-1} \, dx, $$
we can write the inner sum as
$$ \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \int_0^1 (x^{kn-a-1}-x^{kn-1}) \, dx. $$
The sum is finite, so there is no trouble changing the order of summation and integration to find
$$ \int_0^1 \left( \frac{x^{(k-1)n}(1-x^n)}{1-x}-nx^{kn-1} \right) \, dx $$
Now we do the same again with the outer sum, which is for the time being also finite:
$$ \int_0^1 \left( \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\sum_{k=1}^M (x^n)^{k-1} - \frac{n}{x}\sum_{k=1}^M (x^n)^k \right) \, dx = \int_0^1 \left( \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \frac{1-x^{Mn}}{1-x^n} - n\frac{x^{n-1}(1-x^{Mn})}{1-x^n} \right) \, dx $$
At this point, I need to be careful with interchanging the limit and the integral, because the integrands diverge at $x=1$. I shall set the upper limit a bit smaller than $1$, do the easy bit of the integral, and then sort out the rest.

The easy bit is
$$ \int_0^y \left( \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1-x^n} \right) \, dx = [ -\log{(1-x)}+\log{(1-x^n)} ]_0^y = \log{\left(\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\right)}. $$
This clearly tends to $\log{n}$, using L'Hôpital, for example.

It remains to get rid of the nasty term,
$$ \lim_{M \to \infty} \lim_{y \uparrow 1} \int_0^y \left( -\frac{x^{Mn}}{1-x} + n\frac{x^{Mn+n-1}}{1-x^n} \right) \, dx. $$
Taking out a factor of $x^{Mn}$, we have
$$ x^{Mn} \left( \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1-x^n}-\frac{1}{1-x} \right) = x^{Mn}\frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(1+x+\dotsb+x^{n-1})}-1\right) $$
Doing a series expansion about $x=1$ shows that in fact this is continuous in a neighbourhood of $x=1$. It is continuous elsewhere in the interval, and hence bounded above by $C$, say. Then the whole term is bounded above by
$$ \int_0^1 Cx^{Mn} \, dx = \frac{C}{Mn+1} \to 0 $$
as $M \to \infty$, so the whole limit evaluates to $\log{n}$.

Comment: Thanks @Chappers for your answer. Is this the proof of the equality that I had asked? And is it true for every possible value of n?

Comment: @JanEerland I started with your original equation, since it was easier to work with. You're going to run into problems unless $n$ is an integer with defining what $\sum_{a=1}^{n-1}$ is, so it's only going to be valid for integer $n$ in this form.

Comment: So this is valid (proved by your proof above): $$\ln(n)=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\sum\limits _{a=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{kn-a}-\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\frac{n-1}{kn}.$$ but only for every integer n of only positive or negative numbers of n?

Comment: Positive integers only (since otherwise defining the sum is problematic).

Comment: And what about zero?

Comment: If $n=0$ then the $1/(kn)$ term isn't defined?

Comment: So this is true for: every positive number of n (except zero)? $$\ln(n)=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\sum\limits _{a=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{kn-a}-\sum\limits _{k=1}^{M}\frac{n-1}{kn}.$$

Comment: Yes, it is true for $n=1,2,\dotsc$. (zero is not a positive integer. It is a non-negative integer, but not a positive one.)

Comment: Thnxx a lot buddy ;) I'm very thankfull