Extending the Euler-Mascheroni Constant to higher dimensions $\gamma_n$.
The classical Euler-Mascheroni Constant is
$$
\gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \ln(n) \right)
$$
I'm trying to extend $\gamma$ to higher dimensions denoted by $\gamma_n$ and am curious if a higher dimensional generalization of the Euler-Mascheroni Constant is valid?
$2D$ Representation (Classical $\gamma$)
Graphical representation of $\gamma$


Green Bars: Represent the harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$

Orange Area Under Curve: Represents $\int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln(n)$

Blue Dotted Area: Represents the difference to give the Euler—Mascheroni constant


$$
\underbrace{\gamma}_{\text{blue area}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 
    \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}}_{\text{green area}} 
    - 
    \underbrace{\ln(n)}_{\text{orange area}} 
\right)
$$
Applying similar geometric methods, we can extend it to higher dimensions.
For example, consider the following $3D$ representation.
$3D$ Representation ($\gamma_3$)
Visualize revolving the bars around the $x$-axis to form Gabriel's Wedding Cake (an infinite stack of cylinders with volume $\frac{\pi^3}{6}$) and revolve the curve $y=\frac{1}{x}$ to form Gabriel's Horn (volume $\pi$). The difference between these two volumes  represents the Euler—Mascheroni constant $\gamma_3=\frac{\pi^3}{6} - \pi$.
Gabriel's Cake

Gabriel's Horn

Furthermore, each $n$-dimension has its own distinct Euler-Mascheroni constant:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{n-dimension} & \mathbf{\gamma_n} & \mathbf{\approx} \\
\hline
3 & \hspace{5pt} \pi \left( \zeta(2) - 1 \right) \hspace{5pt} & 2.0261201264...\\ \hline
4 & \hspace{5pt} \frac{2}{3} \pi \left( 2 \, \zeta(3) - 1 \right) \hspace{5pt} & 2.9407690791... \\ \hline
5 & \hspace{5pt} \frac{1}{2} \pi^2 \left( \zeta(4) - \frac{1}{3} \right) \hspace{5pt} & 3.6961170085... \\ \hline
6 & \hspace{5pt} \frac{8}{15} \pi^2 \left( \zeta(5) - \frac{1}{4} \right) \hspace{5pt} & 4.1422216722... \\ \hline
7 & \hspace{5pt} \frac{1}{6} \pi^3 \left( \zeta(6) - \frac{1}{5} \right) \hspace{5pt} & 4.2237941871... \\ \hline
8 & \hspace{5pt} \frac{16}{105} \pi^3 \left( \zeta(7) - \frac{1}{6} \right) \hspace{5pt} & 3.9767533569... \\
\hline
\end{array}

Definitions

$\gamma$ - classical Euler-Mascheroni constant.
$\zeta(s)$ - Riemann zeta function.
$\Gamma(s)$ - Gamma function.
$V_c$ - Volume of Gabriel's Wedding Cake in $n$-dimensions.
$V_h$ - Volume of Gabriel's Horn in $n$-dimensions.
$\gamma_n$ - Euler-Mascheroni constant in $n$-dimensions.


Conjecture
For dimension $n \ge 3$, the $n$-dimensional Euler-Mascheroni constant is:
$$
\gamma_n=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)} \left(\zeta(n-1)-\dfrac{1}{n-2}\right)
$$
Proof
The volume of an $(n-1)$-dimensional Hyper-sphere with radius $R$ is
$$
V_{n-1}(R) = \frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}} R^{n-1}}{\Gamma\left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)}
$$
The volume of an $n$-dimensional Hyper-cylinder is
$$
V_{n}(R) = \underbrace{V_{n-1}(R)}_{\text{base}} \times \underbrace{h}_{\text{height}}
$$
The volume of Gabriel's Wedding Cake $V_{c}$ with $R_k = \frac{1}{k}$ and $h=1$ is
\begin{align*}
V_c &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} V_n(R_k) \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{n-1} \\
    &= \frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{n-1}} \\
&= \frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} \zeta(n-1)
\end{align*}
The volume of the $n$-dimensional Gabriel's Horn $V_h$
\begin{align*}
V_h &= \int_1^\infty V_{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \, dx \\
    &= \frac{\pi^{\frac{n - 1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left( \frac{n + 1}{2} \right)} \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{n - 1}} \, dx \\
    &= \frac{\pi^{\frac{n - 1}{2}}}{\, \Gamma\left( \frac{n + 1}{2} \right)} \left(\frac{1}{n - 2} \right)
\end{align*}
The $n$-dimensional Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma_n$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
\gamma_n &= V_c - V_h \\
         &= \frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)} \zeta(n-1) - \frac{\pi^{\frac{n - 1}{2}}}{\, \Gamma\left( \frac{n + 1}{2} \right)} \left(\frac{1}{n - 2} \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi^{\frac{n - 1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left( \dfrac{n + 1}{2} \right)} \left( \zeta(n - 1) - \dfrac{1}{n - 2} \right) \quad \blacksquare
\end{align*}

References

Gabriel's Horn
Gabriel's Wedding Cake
Graphical representation of $\gamma$
The Euler-Mascheroni constant
How to derive the volume of an n-dimensional hypersphere
The volume and surface area of an n-dimensional hypersphere


What's the reason to choose cylinder in $3$ dimensions? Understood the revolution of the bars, just wondering if the choice of the $3$D shape is unique...

Rethinking...this method isn't really linked to the Euler-Mascheroni constant. As noted by @Srini, why use a cylinder shape when a cone/sphere would work too, right? Overall, the method is basically computing the difference between Gabriel's Wedding Cake and Gabriel's Horn in n-dimensions. ;) Anyhow, I learned a lot along the way and thanks for your help!

In your figure for the 3D case, I believe the horn should pass through the left-side of the cylinders instead of the right-side to be consistent with your calculation. The picture makes it look like the volume of the horn is larger than the volume of the cylinders which is backwards. I think its natural to extend the rectangles to cylinders since the intersection along the plane of the x-y axis where $z=0$ is consistent with the 2D case.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46713/euler-mascheroni-constant-expression-further-simplification?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment3319970_46718

Your generalization is valid once you adjust the 2D case to be consistent with the intersection of the x-y plane with Gabriel's horn and the cones in the 3D case as illustrated in Figure (1) below.

Figure (1): Illustration of corrected 2D case

Since $$\int\limits_1^n \frac{1}{x}-\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx=2 \int_1^n \frac{1}{x} \, dx=2 \log(n)\tag{1}$$
the 2D case should be evaluated as
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2}{k}-2 \log (n)\right)=2 \gamma\tag{2}$$
which is consistent with your formula result
$$\gamma_2=\underset{n\to 2}{\text{lim}} \left(\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} \left(\zeta(n-1)-\frac{1}{n-2}\right)\right)=2 \gamma\tag{3}$$
for the case $n=2$.

I believe the function
$$f_\gamma(s)=\frac{\pi^{\frac{s-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)} \left(\zeta(s-1)-\frac{1}{s-2}\right)\tag{4}$$
is analytic with a removable singularity at $s=2$ and $\lim\limits_{s\to\pm\infty} f_\gamma(s)=0$ both of which are suggested by Figure (1) below.

Figure (1): Illustration of $f_\gamma(s)$ for $-10<s<30$

The function $f_\gamma(s)$ has trivial zeros at the negative odd integers as illustrated in Figure (2) below, but the existence and location of non-trivial zeros is more of a mystery to me.

Figure (2): Illustration of $f_\gamma(s)$ for $-10<s<0$


So, the $N$-dimensional constant converges to the $2D$ Euler-Mascheroni constant:
$$
\lim_{n \to 2^+} \frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{2, \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} \left( \zeta(n-1) - \frac{1}{n-2} \right) = \gamma
$$

@vengy The N-dimensional constant evaluated at $N=2$ converges to $\gamma_2=2 \gamma$ per formula (3) above. You've divided formula (3) by 2. It seems to me you're still attempting to evaluate the 2-dimensional case inconsistent with the evaluations for the higher dimensional cases. If you want the 2-dimensional case to evaluate to $\gamma$ instead of $2 \gamma$, then you should also multiply your evaluations for the higher dimensional cases by $\frac{1}{2}$.
