# Series for logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

This is more of a challenge than a question, but I thought I'd share anyway. Prove the following identities, and prove that the pattern continues.
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)=\ln2
\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}-\frac{2}{3n+3}\right)=\ln3
\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{4n+1}+\frac{1}{4n+2}+\frac{1}{4n+3}-\frac{3}{4n+4}\right)=\ln4
\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{etc.}
\end{equation*}
By the way, a good notation for discussing this problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883233/a-certain-harmonic-sum). The problem is to prove that:
$[\overline{1,-1}]=\ln2,\;\;$ $[\overline{1,1,-2}]=\ln3,\;\;$ $[\overline{1,1,1,-3}]=\ln4,\;\;$ $[\overline{1,1,1,1,-4}]=\ln5,\;\;$ etc.

Comment: "challenge" meaning that you already know how to do it?

Comment: Indeed. At the time of writing this comment, one solution has been posted - that way was the way I first did it, too. However, I have since come up with a "nicer" way (without using derivatives or integrals - though it does use the Taylor series for logarithms).

Comment: Apparently, this could also be made computing
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{mn+i}-\frac{1}{mn+m})=-\frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{i}{m}\right)+\gamma }{m}$$ But I am stuck with the summation of the digamma functions.

Comment: Hello! There is a way to do this using no calc; only the fact that $e^x\ge x+1$ and the "intuitively obvious" squeeze theorem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46378/do-these-series-converge-to-logarithms

Comment: @MatsGranvik Ah, so I was 3 years too late when I asked that this summer. (And you were several months late in notifying me! :P) In any case, there's still another proof that no one has yet given on either page — the one I mentioned in my above comment.

Comment: This is one of my favourite discoveries too. But Jaume Oliver Lafont knew about this before me, and probably others too. Regarding proofs, I am not good at understanding them so I can't comment on that. Just one thing, you probably know that there is a simple one column at the time recurrence that your numerators satisfy. Try running that recurrence in two directions simultaneously. What you will get is a matrix with a few interesting properties: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48946/do-these-series-converge-to-the-mangoldt-function
The von Mangoldt function is one of them.

Comment: Here are some related ideas in terms of harmonic numbers:

$$lim_{n->\infty} \left(H_{2n}-H_n\right) = log(2)$$
generalizes to  
$$lim_{n->\infty} \left(H_{pn}-H_{n}\right) = log\left(p\right)$$

Moreover, 
$$lim_{n->\infty} \left(H_{pn}-H_{qn}\right) = log\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$$

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont I believe that those are basically user165670's answer in disguise.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger The cancelled harmonic series should be placed before those, so all these series are then obtained as rearrangements (Riemann series theorem). 
$$lim_{n->\infty} \left(H_n-H_n\right) = log(1)$$

http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602987/134791

Comment: Here is a generalization using sequences instead of explicit limits for the inner summations, so more numbers can be computed, not only log(p/q)
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609512/134791

Answer (score 9):

Let $m\geq 2$. Put:

$$S_m=\sum_{n\geq 0}(\frac{1}{mn+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{mn+m-1}-\frac{m-1}{mn+m}) $$

As $\displaystyle \frac{1}{mn+r}=\int_0^1x^{mn+r-1}dx$, We have 
$$S_m=\int_0^{1}\frac{1+x+\cdots+x^{m-2}-(m-1)x^{m-1}}{1-x^m} dx$$
But
$$1+x+\cdots+x^{m-2}-(m-1)x^{m-1}=(1-x^{m-1})+\cdots+(x^{m-2}-x^{m-1})$$

Hence 
$$1+x+\cdots+x^{m-2}-(m-1)x^{m-1}=[(1-x)(1+x+\cdots x^{m-2})]+\cdots+[x^{m-2}(1-x)]$$

and

$$[(1+x+\cdots x^{m-2})]+\cdots+[x^{m-2}]=1+2x+\cdots+(m-1)x^{m-2}$$

Thus
$$S_m=\int_0^1\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}(k+1)x^{k}}{1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1}}dx=\int_0^1\frac{P^{\prime}(x)}{P(x)}dx=[\log(1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1})]_0^1=\log(m)$$

Comment: This is a really nice answer ! Thanks for providing this solution. Cheers :)

Comment: This was my first solution, too! However, I have since come up with a "nicer" solution in the shower (it doesn't involve any integrals or derivatives, but it does require knowledge of the Taylor series for ln).

Comment: Could you show this solution ?

Comment: Sure - as soon as I get on my computer (am currently on mobile). $\LaTeX$ and phones do not mix.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Done.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46378/do-these-series-converge-to-logarithms

Answer (score 9):

For any $m \in \mathbb{N},$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{1}{mk+1} + \frac{1}{mk+2} + ... + \frac{1}{mk+m-1}- \frac{m-1}{mk+m}\Big)$$ $$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big(\sum_{k=0}^{mn} \frac{1}{mk+1} + ... + \frac{1}{mk+m-1} - \frac{m-1}{mk+m}\Big)$$$$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( \sum_{k=1}^{mn} \frac{1}{k} - m \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{mk} \Big)$$ $$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big(\sum_{k=1}^{mn} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\Big)$$ $$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( \sum_{k=1}^{mn} \frac{1}{k} - \ln(mn) + \ln(mn) - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \Big)$$$$= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( \sum_{k=1}^{mn} \frac{1}{k} - \ln(mn) + \ln(n) - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \Big) + \ln(m)$$ $$= \gamma - \gamma + \ln(m) = \ln(m),$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Wow. That was an interesting approach. Good job!

Comment: Not exactly the same but the second last line in that proof above resembles the answer to this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46713/euler-mascheroni-constant-expression-further-simplification

Answer (score 4):

So far, there is a proof involving differentiation/integration, and a proof involving nothing more than the knowledge that $\gamma$amma exists. Here is my proof, requiring the Taylor series expansion of the logarithm.

The well known Taylor series for $\ln(x)$ is as follows:
$$-\ln(1-x)=\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{x^m}{m}+\cdots$$
which I love, because the exponents correspond to the denominators.

Substituting in $x^m$, we get:
$$-\ln(1-x^m)=\frac{x^m}{1}+\frac{x^{2m}}{2}+\frac{x^{3m}}{3}+\cdots=\frac{m\,x^m}{m}+\frac{m\,x^{2m}}{2m}+\frac{m\,x^{3m}}{3m}+\cdots$$
where I rewrote it slightly so that the exponents still correspond to the denominators.

Subtracting the bottom from the top, we get:
$$\ln\left(\frac{1-x^m}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{-(m-1)x^m}{m}+\\
\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}+\cdots+\frac{-(m-1)x^{2m}}{2m}+\cdots$$
(i.e. the coefficients are $-(m-1)$ where the denominator is a multiple of $m$, and $1$ otherwise.)

The LHS can be rewritten as $\ln(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^m)$. So, plugging in $x=1$:
$$\ln(m)=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots-\frac{m-1}{m}+\frac{1}{m+1}+\cdots-\frac{-(m-1)}{2m}+\cdots$$
which is what was meant to be proved.

Answer (score 1):

The partial sums of this series can be written in a simple form. The generic term is
$$
\frac1{mk+1}+\cdots+\frac1{mk+(m-1)}-\frac{m-1}{mk+m}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\frac1{mk+j}\right)-\frac1{k+1},$$
so the sum of the first $n$ terms is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\frac1{mk+j}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{mn}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\sum_{k=n+1}^{mn}\frac1k.$$
Let $n\to\infty$. The limit of the RHS is $\log(m)$, by [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4356435/215011):

---

**Claim:** Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be sequences of positive integers with $b_n\ge a_n\to\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=c$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=a_n}^{b_n}\frac1k=\log c.$$

Comment: Nice! How did you find a 7.5-year-old question?

Comment: Haha, from this even older question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46378/215011 which can be solved the same way.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger The same device can be applied to your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/883233/215011 , if you're interested in seeing an elementary solution

Answer (score 0):

Having $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ for all expressions,

(especially for $\left(H_{xn}-H_n\right)$ combinations to avoid $\infty-\infty$ complications)

and

having $H_n=\sum_{1}^n\frac 1i$;

No 1 expression left side equals: $H_{2n}-H_n$

No 2 expression left side equals: $H_{3n}−H_n$

No 3 expression left side equals: $H_{4n}−H_n$

Having  as Euler–Mascheroni constant;
$$=H_n-\ln n$$

Generalizing:
$$=H_{xn}-\ln xn$$
$$\Rightarrow H_{xn}-H_n=\ln xn -\ln n$$
$$\Rightarrow H_{xn}-H_n=\ln x $$
where $x\geq 1$.

Accordingly;

No 1 expression: $H_{2n}-H_n=\ln 2$

No 2 expression: $H_{3n}−H_n=\ln 3$

No 3 expression: $H_{4n}−H_n=\ln 4$

Comment: This is essentially @user165670's answer above, but with fewer details and less rigour.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, to my surprise our comments seem to have vanished! Have you flagged them to a moderator for deletion? I wouldn't mind that, since they were not valuable, but I'd like to know (for my curiosity) how they disappeared.

Comment: @AlexM. …No, I did not… I don't know who deleted them

Comment: I read all comments...

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize the concept of $H_xn-H_n=\ln x$.

I was excited with the idea of $H_{-n]-H_n=\ln {-1}$.

Comment: ... and sorry for the mess!
This area is not working like Word...

Comment: It should have been:
"I was excited with the idea of $H_{-n}-H_n=\ln {-1}$."

Comment: OK... seemingly it worked now.
Next time -if I ever do- it will be better!